# Use compiled LLVM/clang without gcc

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, clang

I have been trying to compile LLVM/clang from source, both by myself and using [this script](https://github.com/ClangBuiltLinux/tc-build). I am compiling clang using gcc 11.2, which itself was also built from source, and hence resides in a non-default location on my system (/scratch/opt/gcc-ml-11.2). Note that it only works with a gcc that was compiled with multilib enabled.

The problem is that I can use the compiled `clang` and `clang++` binaries only if I supply the gcc location as follows: `--gcc-toolchain=/scratch/opt/gcc-ml-11.2.0`. Without that flag, I run into linker errors:

```
clang test.c -o test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I do not understand why a clang compiled binary needs to link against some kind of gcc library and why clang does not supply the `crtbeginS.O` file.

I have also tried using the LLVM linker as well as the LLVM standard library for C++ test applications, i.e., `"-fuse-ld=lld -stdlib=libc++`. This did not help either.

While I could just `export CXXFLAGS=--gcc-toolchain=/scratch/opt/gcc-ml-11.2.0`, I am not sure whether this is the right approach. Shouldn't clang/LLVM be able to function without a gcc installation?

I have also tried using my clang installation with the `--gcc-toolchain=/scratch/opt/gcc-ml-11.2.0` flag to compile clang again, but the new binary also requires the gcc-toolchain flag.

Should I just globally export the path to my gcc toolchain? Why is this necessary? Isn't clang a standalone compiler that - if supplied with the option to use its own standard library - does not require gcc?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best,
Maxbit

Comment: rebuild clang with clang to eliminate gcc runtime dependencies.

Comment: This mentions path settings to not need to specify on the command line: https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-a-modern-host-c-toolchain

Comment: @stark I have tried that. So I built clang again with clang using the --gcc-toolchain flag. However, the "new" clang still only functions with that flag.

Comment: @crashmstr Thank you for the pointer. However, the site only mentioned that the --gcc-toolchain flag is required in order for clang to be able to use the gcc standard library. It explicitly says using `-stdlib=libc++`, using gcc should not be necessary. However, my linker error is not regarding the stdlib, but regarding "-lgcc", whatever library that is.

Comment: You need to build compiler-rt and other libraries (libunwind, libcxxabi, libcxx) from the LLVM project as well and specify that you want to use them by default if you don't want any dependency on GCC/libstdc++. There are cmake flags to choose the defaults and command line flags for the driver, e.g. `--rtlib=compiler-rt` (assuming you have build compiler-rt). The default build configuration will use `--rtlib=libgcc`, i.e. it uses the GCC runtime library.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you very much. Indeed, I have built all LLVM projects, not only clang. Using `--rtlib=compiler-rt` made the `-lgcc` linker errors go away. The remaining errors are:

```
clang test.c -fuse-ld=lld -stdlib=libc++ --rtlib=compiler-rt test.c -o test
ld.lld: error: cannot open crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
ld.lld: error: cannot open crtendS.o: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any idea what flag I might still be missing?

If I don't use lld and ld instead, it just complains about crtbeginS.o, not crtendS.O.

Comment: At least some time ago there was an issue that LLVM did not ship any crtbegin* and crtend* files. I think I simply copied them from libgcc at the time to get it working. (You might need to check licensing when doing that.) I don't know how/whether this was resolved in the end, but you can see some discussion about this topic here: https://reviews.llvm.org/D28791, https://reviews.llvm.org/D59264

Comment: If I understand correctly the current LLVM should build `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` if the `COMPILER_RT_BUILD_CRT` cmake flag is set and then when using compiler-rt as rtlib it should use these instead of `crtbeginS.o` and other variants.

Comment: Yeah, this is also what I understand from https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt; but as ON seems to be the default, I do not understand why it did not build them for me. There is neither the shared (`crtbeginS.o`) version nor a `crtbegin.o` file in my install directory. For now, I have just copied GCC's shared libraries and it worked. I will try to figure out why it didn't built these two object files. Thank you so much for your help.